# custom maps in zingchart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, maps

I am using the [Zingchart](http://www.zingchart.com) library to add a map and charts to my website.

For the Map there are some predefined maps included in the library. Is there a way I can define my own map? I am looking for a way to enter the coordinates of the polygons 
I want with their name, and they get loaded.

I tried too see how they are done by looking at the source code but I have the minified version and its not very intuitive to figure out how to modify them.

Comment: You can do this with plain html using the img, map and area tags.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp (though they don't give an example of poly there) or SVG as with raphael.js here: http://raphaeljs.com/world/ ... or does it _have_ to be something that starts with zing?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the polygon coordinates you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Zingchart Maps Module docs](http://www.zingchart.com/reference/modules-maps.html) include a handful country maps as demos. As you said, these are the predefined maps the library comes with. If you load up one of the maps (on their docs page) and right click, their custom context menu should show the option "view source", amongst other export options. Within the result window, you will see the **Parsed JSON** tab. This JSON object defines the map. For example, an excerpt of Argentina's map definition looks like this:

```
...
{
    "type":"poly",
    "id":"NQ",
    "points":[[183,180],
            [183,181],
            [184,182],
            [185,182],
            [185,183],
            [185,184],
            [186,185],
            [186,185],
 ...
```

In order to define you own map, you simply need to mirror this structure. Start by cloning any of the included maps and substitute in your own values for `points`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: THanks, I tried that but when I use that the map stops appearing. I noticed there are some null values in the middle of the coordinates. any idea what they mean?

Comment: In the case of Argentina, the null values are the area in between the mainland and the island at the bottom of the country.